# C# linkedlist find method throws error "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Item' because it is not a delegate type"

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LinkedList<Item> list = new LinkedList<Item>();

        // Add some items to the list
        list.AddLast(new Item { Id = 1, Name = "Item 1" });
        list.AddLast(new Item { Id = 2, Name = "Item 2" });
        list.AddLast(new Item { Id = 3, Name = "Item 3" });

        // Find an item by its id
        int idToFind = 2;
        LinkedListNode<Item> node = list.Find((Item x) => x.Id == idToFind);
        if (node != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found item: {0}", node.Value.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item not found");
        }
    }
}

class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am searching for the reason why lambda is not allowed in Find method but same is working in FirstOrDefault?

Comment: I don't see any overloads of [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.find?view=net-7.0), which takes an item and returns the node. Is your `.Find` an extension method? If so, do you have the appropriate `using` to include it?

Comment: `Find` doesn't expect a lambda but an `Item`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.find?view=net-7.0

Comment: Did you mean `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Find`?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain LinkedList is generic collection, why we can't find any item like other collections?

Comment: because there is no  `Find`-method for **collections**, but just for `List<T>` and `Array`. So someone needed to implement something that `FirstOrDefault` already does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Find` doesn't expect a lambda but an `Item`: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.find?view=net-7.0.

So you'd need this:

```
LinkedListNode<Item> node = list.Find(myItem);
```

which is pretty unhandy when you want to search for an `Item` that satisfies a specific condition. That's where `FirstOrDefault` comes into play:

```
LinkedListNode<Item> node = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == idToFind);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in others `List` type instance you can use `Find(Predicate<T> match)` to get the item which you want. For example

```
var list = new List<string>().Find(x => x == "a");
```

This is because `List<T>` implement the method

```
public class List<T> 
{
    public T? Find(Predicate<T> match)
}
```

But now which you used is `LinkedListNode<T>` the `Find()` implemention
in it is

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    public LinkedListNode<T>? Find(T value)
}
```

So that's why you got a complile error.